# PHP. usort() внутри foreach

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка, foreach

Имеется ассоциативный массив массивов объектов. Необходимо отсортировать массивы объектов. Сам ассоциативный массив трогать не надо.

Пример (цифры вместо объектов для упрощения):

```
$arr['key1'] = [2, 3, 1];
$arr['key2'] = [20, 30, 1];
...
```

1) Код ниже не меняет порядка элементов в массиве массивов:

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
    usort($item, function ($a, $b) {
        return $b->value <=> $a->value;
    });
}
```

Массив объектов `$arr['key1']` не поменял порядка элементов.

2) Немного поменяв код:

```
// foreach ($result as $item) {
    usort($result['key1'], function ($a, $b) {
        return $b->value <=> $a->value;
    });
// }
```

Объекты в `$arr['key1']` отсортированы.

Я не силен в PHP. Возможно есть нюансы в работе foreach и как передаются значения(по ссылке или копируются). Вопрос: Почему так получилось и не работает 1 вариант? Как правильно и "аккуратно" отсортировать массивы внутри ассоциативного массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Код ниже не меняет порядка элементов в массиве массивов:

целиком это утверждение корректно. А вот если взять только первую часть

> Код ниже не меняет порядка элементов

то она будет ошибочна. можете в цикле сделать `print_r($item)` и увидите что элементы будут отсортированы.

Суть проблемы в том, что вы сортируете копию каждого элемента основного массива. Возьмите элемент по ссылке, и тогда все будет работать ожидаемо

```
foreach($result as &$item){
     ...
}
```